# Java service is restarted 4 or 5 times

Tags: java, java-service-wrapper

I am running a Java service to poll data from database. 
In my class, I have a thread, which looks for data in db every 5 seconds...
At particular time(say like 6 PM when out of business hours), i make my thread to sleep to some configured time delay.

Problem: when I make my thread to sleep, it seems my Java service is restarted...
Why am I getting 4, 5 JVM launched...
Please help me to understand....

```
ERROR  | wrapper  | 2013/12/21 15:40:10 | JVM did not exit on request, termination requested.
STATUS | wrapper  | 2013/12/21 15:40:10 | JVM exited after being requested to terminate.
STATUS | wrapper  | 2013/12/21 15:40:14 | Launching a JVM...
INFO   | wrapper  | 2013/12/21 15:40:14 | Command: "C:\Windows\system32\java.exe" -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252 -Duser.language=en -Djava.library.path="../lib" -classpath "java-windows-OSN-service.jar;../lib/wrapper.jar;../lib/log4j-1.2.15.jar;../lib/sqljdbc4.jar" -Dwrapper.key="PHie-UB6SOJ9BBlfqJKjPuopQ40gFfnH" -Dwrapper.port=32000 -Dwrapper.jvm.port.min=31000 -Dwrapper.jvm.port.max=31999 -Dwrapper.pid=6116 -Dwrapper.version="3.5.22-pro" -Dwrapper.native_library="wrapper" -Dwrapper.arch="x86" -Dwrapper.cpu.timeout="10" -Dwrapper.jvmid=4 -Dwrapper.lang.domain=wrapper -Dwrapper.lang.folder=../lang com.servion.service.ServiceController
INFO   | jvm 4    | 2013/12/21 15:40:15 | Control Event: 1
ERROR  | wrapper  | 2013/12/21 15:40:43 | Startup failed: Timed out waiting for a signal from the JVM.
```

Comment: What's running the JVM?

Comment: Well you obviously aren't running it from the commandline, what are use using to wrap the java application in a service?

Comment: I am using tanukisoftware to wrap and my service is to look for data in db every 5 seconds...

Comment: have you try with another tool to run your service, like JavaExe for example ?

Answer (score 7):

Wrapper software communicates with your started JVM very often and checks whether it's alive or not. When you make your application sleep, that communication fails and the wrapper notifies the process hung and attempts to restart it. To avoid this you have to configure the **wrapper.ping.timeout** in your wrapper conf. To avoid timeout set the property to "0".

Check more details on ping timeout- [wrapper.ping.timeout configuration](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/prop-ping-timeout.html#timeout)

If you have any timeout issue in the start up of the application 
(The default timeout value is 30 seconds) 
Change the value in wrapper conf to "0" in order to avoid restarting application.
**wrapper.startup.timeout**=0

Check more details on startup timeout - [wrapper.startup.timeout configuration](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/prop-startup-timeout.html)

Answer (score 0):

Just a hunch, but my guess is that when you make your application sleep, you also stop the watchdog mechanism from Tanukisoft to respond to probes, so Tanuki thinks your application is frozen.

Have a look at the integration methods for standalone apps with Tanukisoft : http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/integrate.html

Comment: Did you read http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/integrate.html ? Did you implement one of the method ? Which one ?