# Java Server Wrapper (tanuki) - Startup failed: Timed out waiting for a signal from the JVM

Tags: java, java-service-wrapper, tanuki

I'm trying to set up an own application with the `Tanuki Java Service Wrapper`.

The setup and configuration worked fine but after starting my application via the wrapper (what also works) it gets shut down after a while because the wrapper "timed out waiting for a signal from the JVM".

My application is working after the start and still gets shut down.

I'm currently still in the setup / test phase so I just start the wrapper via the `bat` file and not as Windows service yet.

I had two ideas why this could be:

1) The main thread terminates after starting a few other threads. I tried to let the main thread just wait forever instead of terminating but that didn't help (besides that the wrapper should also work without the main thread I guess).

2) My program is mostly just waiting for events (directory watch service) but even if I trigger some events it still gets shut down.

I tried to disable the JVM ping check via `wrapper.ping.timeout=0` but that didn't work either and it would be nice if I had the check in case the app would really hang.

I'm using `jdk1.7.0_79` and `wrapper-windows-x86-32-3.5.27`.

Comment: Absolutely not an answer to your question, but: does Tanuki offer the possibility to start the wrapper exe directly and not as a service ? You could try that approach to find out if something with JNI is going wrong. And: have you thought of using Apache Commons daemon ? I migrated to that solution because (at least at that time) Tanuki didn't provide a free wrapper for x64.

Comment: I'm using the provided `bat` file and haven't installed it as service yet. The `bat` is setting a ton of parameters and starts the exe. Apache Commons would be an option, too, but maybe I also find a solution to my tanuki problem.

Answer (score 8):

Setting `wrapper.startup.timeout=0` as well did the trick for me since the JVM is sleeping / not responding right after the start and this is a different check than the `wrapper.ping`

Found my solution here:

[Java service is restarted 4 or 5 times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20718058/java-service-is-restarted-4-or-5-times)